# How to select an item from a list in python

Tags: python, list, select

I am have a list as shown
`Employees=['Harry Grapes','Marg Plum','Monica Nguyen']`
I would like to create a selection feature that allows the user to select the Employee on a menu.
Something like:

Please select the employee

1. Harry
2. Marg
3. Monica

If they type 1 it selects Harry from the list.
Atm I just cycle through all the employees with a for loop.
`for CurrentEmployee in range(3):`

Comment: Are the items in the menu in the same order as the employes in the list? If so, you can use indexing to get them directly rather than using a for loop to search. If you still need more help, please post the code that you wrote so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, A certain degree of research effort is expected from posters. If you query your question in your favorite search engine, you'll find lot of easy tutorials on how to solve your problem.

Comment: BTW, is a convention (not mandatory, but useful whether you have to use somebody else's code, or reuse or share yours) to write the names of variables with lower case in the first letter. names starting with Capital are normally used for classes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your **question** about this task? What happens when you try to write code to solve the problem? "If they type 1 it selects Harry from the list." Okay, so what exactly does the program need to do, step by step? Try to explain the reasoning. What should we do with the input (for example, do we need to interpret it as a number?) What is the rule that tells us that `Harry` is the correct result in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate`:

```py
Employees=['Harry Grapes', 'Marg Plum', 'Monica Nguyen']

for pos, employee in enumerate(Employees):
    # i starts from 0
    print(f"{str(pos+1)}. {employee.split()[0]}")
    
choice = int(input('Choose from options: '))

print('You chose ' + Employees[choice-1])
```

Comment: BTW `enumerate` has an optional parameter `start` that allows you to set the counter, so you could start counting from 1, to avoid using `i+1`.

Comment: `str(i+1)` is unnecessary in formatted strings. You can just use `f"{i+1}..."`

Comment: @kevinbauer-laufer learning how to code takes struggling with concepts until they are your own. I would suggest taking Lakshay's answer and playing around with the bits you don't understand. print(...) is really helpful here. Plus there are 3 bugs from referencing variables that don't exist in Lakshay's code. But those can be fixed easily even by somebody new to programming. I think this gives you an excellent head start on the question from your class.

Comment: Hi @lakshayGMZ thankyou for your answer, i am new to coding so it took me a bit to understand the code haha. I replaced your undefined `i`, `j` and `a` with `position`, `CurrentEmployee` and `Employees`. And also to save me from having to type `choice - 1` all the time i just made it `choice = int(input('Choose from options: ')) - 1 `

Comment: @lakshayGMZ while your code had bugs I will definitely upvote your post as it got me in the right direction so that i could do the rest myself thankyou

Comment: ah yes i was testing it in my editor but i forgot to change the i j to pos and employee. sorry if you had hard time understand the code and i ahve editted the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can store the name elements to dictionary and get the data from the user to print
the name.

```
Employees = ['Harry Grapes', 'Marg Plum', 'Monica Nguyen']

names = []
for i in Employees:
    names.append(i.split()[0]) # take first word of each element
names_dict = {}
for index, word in enumerate(names, start=1):
    names_dict[index] = word  # store index and the elements in dict
print(names_dict)
user = int(input('enter the number:'))
print(names_dict.get(user))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Employees = ['Harry Grapes', 'Marg Plum', 'Monica Nguyen']
print("Please select the employee")
for i in range(len(Employees)):
    print(i+1,'. ',Employees[i])
choice = int(input())
selectedEmp = Employees[choice-1]
```